# ¿Cómo puedo asignar mas atributos al objeto del autocomplete? - Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Estoy tratando de asignar más atributos a mi objeto que llena el *autocomplete* de **Jquery ui**. Cuando lo recorro y trato de asignar cada atributo a un objeto los dos que no son *Id* y *label*, me aparecen como **undefined**.

```
carga_autocompletado_puesto: function (puestos_list) {
            var puestos = puestos_list;
            var myobject;
            var array = [];
            console.log(puestos);
            for (var i = 0; i < puestos.length; i++) {
                myobject = new Object();
                const puesto = puestos[i];
                myobject.id = puesto.IdPuesto;
                myobject.label = puesto.Puesto;
                myobject.Interna = puesto.TarifaInterna;
                myobject.Externa = puesto.TarifaExterna;
                array.push(myobject);
            }

            $("#nombrePuestoModals").autocomplete({
                source: array,
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#IdPuestoModals").val(ui.item.id);
                    $("#IdTipoTarifaModals").empty();
                    $("#IdTipoTarifaModals").append('<option id="Interna" value="' + ui.item.Interna + '"> Interna </option>');
                    $("#IdTipoTarifaModals").append('<option id="Externa" value="' + ui.item.Externa + '"> Externa </option>');
                }
            })

        },
```

Comment: podrías adjuntar una captura de console.log(puestos) para poder ver como viene la información y poderte ayudar mejor